# If the body continuously produces new sperm, how is there room for it?

Tags: human-biology

If you never ejaculated, how is there room for the constantly generated new sperm? I mean, is there always room for more?

Answer (score 1):

Your testes are a sort of waiting room where sperm hang out, and if ejaculation does not occur, they eventually die, just like red blood cells (or any of your body's cells). Once cells in your body die, they are broken down, and your body uses the components and nutrients to create new cells.

So it's a continual cycle of replacement and death.

Read more [here](https://www.thenakedscientists.com/articles/questions/what-happens-sperm-isnt-ejaculated)

Comment: Hi @J.W., Welcome to Bio.SE, and thanks for the post! You would receive much better response (i.e., more upvotes) if you wrote a more substantial answer. It's great to link to a resource, but providing a bit more info *here* would make this a stronger answer. It's also great to use very accessible language in your answer (e.g., "waiting room" and "hang out"), but following this language up with more biologically appropriate terminology helps provide a greater sense of credibility to your answer. Please consider revising and adding more detail to your answer. Thanks!